# Laravel: How to use the ignore rule in Form Request Validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-validation

Laravel has a 'unique' rule with an 'except' clause.  From the validation documentation, it takes this form:

```
unique:table,column,except,idColumn
```

My application has a 'shop' entity.  When the user updates the shop's profile, I have a Form Request, with a validation rule configured as follows:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'shop.name' => 'required|string|max:100|unique:shops,name,except,id',
    ];
}
```

(The primary key on my `shops` table is `id`).

The problem is that Laravel does not take any notice of the 'except' clause.  This makes sense (sort of) since the shop ID is not being injected into the Form Request. I can inject `id` as just another form value, but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I get this rule working in a Form Request?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To use the `except` clause of the [`unique` rule](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique), we need to provide the *value* of the field on the record that we want the rule to ignore *directly in the rule itself*.

So, if we want a unique `name` field for every record *except* for on the record that the request updates, we need to add the value of the ID field to ignore:

```php
class UpdateShopRequest extends FormRequest
{
    ...
    public function rules() 
    {
        return [
            'shop.name' => 'unique:shops,name,' . $this->shop['id'],
        ];
    }
}
```

As shown, this rule will cause validation to fail if any row contains the same shop name *unless* the row's `id` matches `$this->shop['id']`. This example assumes that our form contains a [*nested input field*](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#a-note-on-nested-attributes) for the record's ID attribute because this particular question is performing validation on an array input:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="shop[id]" value="{{ $shop->id }}">
```

...which lets us fetch the value within the request like we can with any other request.

However, most forms do not contain arrays, so—in other cases—the validation rule will likely refer to the input field directly (without nested identifiers):

```php
'name' => 'unique:shops,name,' . $this->id,
```

More typically, we pass the record ID as a route parameter, which we can retrieve using the request's `route()` method:

```php
'name' => 'unique:shops,name,' . $this->route('id'),
```

...which works if we have a route defined similarly to:

```php
Route::post('shops/{id}', ...);
```

The fourth parameter to the `unique` validation rule lets us specify which column the `except` clause applies to, and defaults to `id`, so we can leave it off if we're just comparing the record's ID.

The rule looks a bit clumsy when we just concatenate the column value, especially for a field with a lot of other rules. Since version 5.3, Laravel provides a more elegant syntax to create a `unique` rule with an `except` clause:

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
...
return [
    'name' => [ 
        'required', 
        'string', 
        'max:100', 
        Rule::unique('shops', 'name')->ignore($this->id, 'optional_column'), 
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks Cy, that is an outstanding explanation...  I had lost sight of the fact that the Form Request was still just a request!

Answer (score 5):

> This example assumes that our form contains an array input field for the record's ID attribute because the question is performing validation on an array input: 
>    `<input type="hidden" name="shop[id]" value="{{ $shop->id }}">`

Laravel 5.8: I've tried you solution right now, **without adding the input**, it's working well. Because Laravel pass the Shop object into request (shown with dd() into rules() )

Just:

```
`public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'unique:shops,name,'.$this->shop->id
    ];
}`
```

Comment: Romain, the `<input>` in my answer was just an illustration for the example. A real application will likely have a different setup. I just wanted to provide some context by showing a basic field that might produce the value in the form request object.

Answer (score 2):

I use this solution in laravel 9, assuming that you use route model binding and resource controller, and do not have to add hidden input for the model id.

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        'buy' => 'required|numeric|gt:0',
        'sell' => 'required|numeric|gt:0',
        'date' => 'required|' . Rule::unique('prices')->ignore($this->price),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for laravel 8 use $this->get('id') to exclude current record to taste

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class Update extends FormRequest
{
  public function rules()
  {
    return [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:shops,slug,'. $this->get('id')],
    ];
  }
}
```